# dynamic UILabels which push the labels below - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I'm trying to build a tableView, which each cell is built by an imageView and labels.
the problem occurs when one of the labels is more than one sentence, and the result is, that label is being written over the label below. when I give the labels greater height, the labels doesn't start at the place I want them to. labels with one sentence starts with a gap between the labels...

[image]
[image]

**Answer:**

Just make sure to to CANCEL autoLayout. in my situation, I don't need it...

```
                titleLabel.text = @"Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla";
                [titleLabel sizeToFit];

                [abstractLabel setText:@"bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla"];
                CGRect abstractFrame = titleLabel.frame;
                abstractFrame.origin.y = titleLabel.frame.origin.y + titleLabel.frame.size.height;
                abstractFrame.size.width = 180;
                [abstractLabel setFrame:abstractFrame];
                [abstractLabel sizeToFit];
```

*got the idea from ate50eggs - [Find UILabel bottom position so a second UILabel can be created below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158518/find-uilabel-bottom-position-so-a-second-uilabel-can-be-created-below)

Comment: Autolayout is your friend. It is amazing for situations like this, I strongly suggest you read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Subclass of UITableViewCell and align the labels yourself. You can calculate the size of the string to display with the `sizeWithFont:` methods of NSString. UILabel does not support vertical alignment.

Comment: No, the solution here is to use autolayout, not hack around with a subclass.

Comment: Yes, Autolayout could also be a solution.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII how can you deal with calculating height of UILabel with autolayout? Just wondering...i've never used auto layout, does it specifically solve this issue or is there some other aspect i am missing?

Comment: Autolayout is checked... still, nada :/

Answer (score 0):

You can make dynamic label size and wordwrap. Like this one:

```
    currentLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    currentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    NSString *string = @"blablablablabla";
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(kLabelWIdth, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [string sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    [currentLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(currentLabel.frame.origin.x, currentLabel.frame.origin.y, labelSize.width, labelSize.height)];
```